# Xcode simulator is not showing swift ui place holder text

Tags: ios, swift

**I have text fields that have placeholder text inside them, on the preview screen in swift UI it shows up however the simulator with Xcode doesn't show the placeholder text.**

It works in the preview but not in the Xcode Simulator so is it just a bug in swift UI or my code?

Images below 
[SwiftUI preview screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib2Wh.png) 
[Simulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alzWm.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct doctor: View {
@State var userInputone: String = ""
@State var userInputtwo: String = ""
@State var userInputthree: String = ""
@State var userInputfour: String = ""
@State var userInputfive: String = ""
@State var userInputsix: String = ""

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Color.white
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack{
            Text("Whats up Doc?")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)



            Text("Let's get to know each other")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

                 .padding()

            .shadow(radius:10)
            TextField("FirstName", text: $userInputone)
            .padding()
             .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
            .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding()

            .shadow(radius:10)
            TextField("LastName", text: $userInputtwo)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
                 .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding()
               .shadow(radius:10)


            TextField("LastName", text: $userInputthree)
                .padding()
              .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
                  .cornerRadius(15)
                   .padding()
        .shadow(radius:10)
            TextField("LastName", text: $userInputfour)
                    .padding()
                   .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
                   .cornerRadius(15)
                                  .padding()
            .shadow(radius:10)
            TextField("LastName", text: $userInputfive)
                 .padding()
                .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
               .cornerRadius(15)
               .padding()
            .shadow(radius:10)
            TextField("LastName", text: $userInputsix)
              .padding()
              .background(Color(red: 0.937, green: 0.952, blue: 0.956))
               .cornerRadius(15)
               .padding()
           .shadow(radius:10)

            NavigationLink(destination: createaccount()){

               Text("Next")
             .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
              .padding(.all, 20.0)
              .frame(height: 44.0)
            .frame(width: 300.0)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.gray, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
          .cornerRadius(20)


        }
        }


    }




}
}

struct doctor_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    doctor()
}
}
```

Comment: what version of `xcode` do you use? It's ok for me.

Comment: @Mac3n Xcode Version 11.3.1

Comment: I used the same version, but it's fine for me and shows the placeholder on simulator

Comment: @Mac3n could it be because the simulator is in dark mode?

Comment: Yes! It is because of dark mode, and in dark mode apple change the placeholder color that can't be seen in your background. you should define a new background color for dark mode too

Comment: @Mac3n how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Because of the dark mode, the placeholder not visible on Textfield background with a color you defined.
The solution could be this:

in  `Assets.xcassets` define new Color, from the right side in inspector change Appearance to `Any, Dark` and change your color to what you preferred. Then you can use it as a background in your Textfield

[image]